# C - memory management

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I just wrote some C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    void **data;
    time_t lastModified;
} container;

container *container_init() {
    container *c = malloc(sizeof(container));
    void *data = NULL;
    c->data = &data;
    c->lastModified = time(NULL);
    return c;
}

void *container_getData(container *c) {
    void **containerData = c->data;
    return *containerData;
}

// only pass manually allocated data that can be free()'d!
void container_setData(container *c, void *data) {
    free(container_getData(c));
    c->data = &data;
}

void container_free(container *c) {
    free(container_getData(c)); // <--- THIS LINE
    free(c);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        char *data = strdup("Hi, I don't understand pointers!");
        container *c = container_init();
        container_setData(c, data);
        container_free(c);
    }
}
```

My logic was the following: When I call `container_setData()`, the old data is `free()`'d and a pointer to the new data is stored. That new data will have to be released at some point. That happens for the last time during the call to `container_free()`.

I have marked a line in the `container_free()` function. I would have sworn I'd need that line in order to prevent a memory leak. However, I can't use the line ("object beeing freed was not allocated") and there's no memory leak if I delete it. How does the string from my loop ever get released?!

Could someone explain where the error is?

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to a pointer in your struct?

Comment: @Brian: I reasoned: `void *` can be anything, I want a _pointer_ to anything, so I should use `void **`. I guess that's pretty flawed thinking ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c->data = &data;
```

stores the address of the pointer `data` (the argument to your function), not the actual pointer. I.e., you're storing a pointer to a temporary.

You could have built the `container` structure with just a `void *data` member.

Comment: Can I fix that by changing `void container_setData(container *c, void *data)` to `void container_setData(container *c, void **data)` and `c->data = &data;` to `c->data = data;`?

Comment: @user: I don't immediately oversee the consequences of doing that. I suspect undefined behavior is just around the corner, but I can't prove it just yet. I recommend you use a `void*` member in `container` instead.

Comment: @user: figured it out: that would move the problem up one level, into `main`, as you'd be storing the address of the `data` variable in the loop. Use a plain `void*`.

Comment: Oh yeah! I have a hard time really understanding pointers... So thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

To explain larsmans answer with code make these changes:

```
typedef struct {
    void *data;
    time_t lastModified;
} container;


void *container_getData(container *c) {
   return c->data;
}

void container_setData(container *c, void *data) {
    free(c->data);
    c->data = data;
}

void container_free(container *c) {
    free(c->data); 
    free(c);
}
```

And other changes too -- this just gets you on the right track.

Comment: `container_init` also needs fixing. The change affects two lines of code.

Comment: @larsman : yes exactly, that is why I say there are other changes needed. :)